# Arbitrary $n-\text{masses}$ for $n-\text{points}$ along the same cirunference create a $n-\text{regular}$ polygon, for $n=3, 4, 5.$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, celestial-mechanics

Suppose three points $(q_1,q_2,q_3)$ of abritrary masses $(m_1,m_2,m_3)$ are on a circunference with center at the origin, creating a triangle (non necessarily equilateral).

Suppose the the barycenter and the center of mass are in the origin. Prove that all masses are equal $m_1=m_2=m_3$, and prove that the triangle is equilateral.

I began by using the definition of barycenter $G = \frac{1}{3}(q_1+q_2+q_3)$

As the barycenter is in the origin, $G=0$, so I conclude that $q_1=-q_2-q_3$.

Then, as $m_1q_1+m_2-q_2+m_3q_3=0$ because the center os mass is in the origin, I followed that
$$-m_1q_2-m_1q_3+m_2q_2+m_3q_3=0$$

Thus, $m_1=m_2=m_3$.

For a lemma I proved in class I concluded that the triangle is equilateral.

Now, my doubt:

> First, I don't know if I forgot something, or I am using what I want to prove. Second, how do I prove the same thing por $n=4, 5$ making a square and a pentagon, respectively.

Comment: It won't be true for $n=4$. In a rectangle you can balance things by having diagonally opposite weights equal, but this does not mean all four of them have to be equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is incorrect. Your correctly find that $q_1=-q_2-q_3$ and then find that
$$-m_1q_2-m_1q_3+m_2q_2+m_3q_3=0,$$
from which it follows that
$$(m_2-m_1)q_2+(m_3-m_1)q_3=0.$$
But this does not imply that $m_1=m_2=m_3$.

---

The three points are contained in a plane, and the setup is invariant with respect to rotation or scaling, so without loss of generality we may take coordinates so that $q_1=(1,0)$. It follows that $q_2$ and $q_3$ are points on the unit circle.

Given that the barycenter is at the origin, we have $\tfrac13(q_1+q_2+q_3)=(0,0)$ and hence $q_2+q_3=(-1,0)$. Writing $q_2=(x_2,y_2)$ and $q_3=(x_3,y_3)$ we see that $y_2=-y_3$, and because $q_2$ and $q_3$ lie on the unit circle, it follows that $x_2^2=x_3^2$. Because $x_2+x_3=-1$ we see that $x_2=x_3=-\tfrac12$, which shows that the $q_i$ are the vertices of an equilateral triangle.

Now if $m_1$, $m_2$ and $m_3$ are weights such that
$$m_1q_1+m_2q_2+m_3q_3=0,$$
then comparing $y$-coordinates shows that $m_2=m_3$. Next comparing $x$-coordinates shows that $m_1=\tfrac{m_2+m_3}{2}=m_2=m_3$.

---

For $n=4$ and $n=5$, it does not follow that the points are the vertices of a square or pentagon, respectively, or that the masses are equal.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. If you don't mind, canyou give me any idea for the statement is not true for $n=4,5$?

Comment: @Davshock It suffices to give a counterexample. The comment under your question suggests one; any rectangle has its barycenter at the origin, and if diagonally opposite weights are equal then the center of mass is also at the origin.